# How can EIO be detected during write?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, system, system-calls

According to [Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html), the `EIO` error is caused by a **Physical** I/O issue. I was wondering how `write` can know that there was an I/O issue at all since `write` actually writes to the kernel buffer (*writeback*?) which in turn passes around to several other buffers (disk buffer,etc...) and does not wait until the data is actually written (physically) to the medium.

Comment: Yes, Linux writes most things first into its kernel buffer. Even so, Linux can check the state of the target device before then writing it to the kernel buffer.

Comment: I expect you would find that the error is not necessarily reported on the first `write()` call after the error occurs.  It would be reported when the I/O system in the kernel propagates the error back to the upper layers that the particular device has problems.  In a few cases, options such a `O_SYNC` may mean that a particular `write()` call does wait, but that's quibbling that doesn't invalidate your main point.